# How can I solve the lto1: internal compiler error: in lto_tag_to_tree_code, at lto-streamer.h:1005 that appears after 'make' command

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, g++, internal-compiler-error

I am super desperate...I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
For a robotics class I had to build their project (after cloning it from git) with the make command. After some time i am receiving the following:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8dXO.png)
(...)

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/fia/robotics-course/rai/rai/ry'
         * UpToDate  ../../rai/Kin/libKin.so
         * UpToDate  ../../rai/Core/libCore.so
         * UpToDate  ../../rai/KOMO/libKOMO.so
         * UpToDate  ../../rai/LGP/libLGP.so
g++ -g -march=native -Wall -DRAI_PYBIND `python3-config --cflags` -Wno-terminate -fPIC -std=c++14 -o lgp-py.o -c lgp-py.cpp
         * UpToDate  ../../rai/Operate/libOperate.so
g++ -g -march=native -Wall -DRAI_PYBIND `python3-config --cflags` -Wno-terminate -fPIC -std=c++14 -o ry.o -c ry.cpp
         * UpToDate  ../../rai/Perception/libPerception.so
         * UpToDate  ../../rai/RosCom/libRosCom.so
g++ -L/home/fia/robotics-course/rai/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o libry.so ./lgp-py.o ./ry.o -lCore -lKin -lKOMO -lLGP -lOperate -lRosCom -lPerception `python3-config --ldflags` -lrt -shared 
lto1: internal compiler error: in lto_tag_to_tree_code, at lto-streamer.h:1005
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: g++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../../build/generic.mk:299: recipe for target 'libry.so' failed
make[1]: *** [libry.so] Error 1
make[1]: Target 'default' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fia/robotics-course/rai/rai/ry'
     ***** FAILED    rai/rai/ry/libry.so
```

I am assuming that the line "internal compiler error" shows me whats wrong but I can not figure out how to solve it... I re-installed g++ and also redownloaded the git repository several times but nothing seems to work. I already thought that maybe me Operating System has a problem?
I already thought about reistalling Ubuntu...

So if anyone has an idea i would be super thankful!
Regards
Fia

Comment: Internal Compiler Error is a bug in the compiler. Sometimes it's triggered by a bug in your code. Often you can work around the bug by changing your code.

Comment: You may want to try a newer version of gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Internal compiler error" sounds like there's a bug in the compiler, so here are some ideas to try to work around it.

You could try compiling it with clang++ instead of g++. Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

Then build using something like:

```
CC=clang CXX=clang++ LD=clang make
```

Because the error mentions `lto`, you could also turning link-time optimization off:

```
LDFLAGS=-fno-lto make
```

Comment: the 'LDFLAGS=-fno-lto make' did work thank you so so so much you really helped me!!